BigQuery hangs when called from inside a function
I'm trying to use BigQuery's SQL to call a very simple database table that has less than 10 rows. A strange behavior I noticed is that access to the bigquery tables are unproblematic when calling from outside python functions rather than inside functions.
I've printed out the os.env and client credentials for both inside and outside and they match letter for letter
print(client)
print(dir(client))  # List attributes of the client
print(client._credentials)

Let's say I have a python file called utils.py.. here's what I have in it
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
print("outside query")
inside_query = client.query("SELECT 1")   
rows = inside_query.result()
for row in rows:
    print(row)


def select_rows(table,  fields):

    print("inside query")
    inside_query = client.query("SELECT 1")   
    rows = inside_query.result()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

what I see printed is
outside query
Row((1,), {'f0_': 0})
inside query
the inside query just hangs... where nothing happens. I've tried doing try and exception blocks, timeouts for the queries and the behavior is all the same.
